# WPF Program shutdown with prompt

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I wrote this code to handle the shutdown of the program/window when I press the Exit-Button:

```
private void MIExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var close = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close the programm?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
        if (close == MessageBoxResult.No)
            return;
        else
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

The problem is I have to press "yes" twice for the application to close and I don`t understand why.

Thank you,
Filippo

Answer (score 1):

ok sorry... I know why. I handled this for the "X" symbol top right on the window:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var close = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close the programm?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
        if (close == MessageBoxResult.No)
            e.Cancel = true;
        else
            e.Cancel = false;
    }
```

and obviously the messageBox appears two times...

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your Code you posted.
Probably you have somewhere else a mistake.

I tried it like this:
Xaml:
`<Button Click="MIExit_click">Exit</Button>`

C#:

```
private void MIExit_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("close?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    else return;
}
```

Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly subscribing to the event twice? I would first handle the event so it doesn't bubble up, then add a simple flag so that your `MessageBox` does not get called twice.

```
private bool _shuttingDown;
private void MIExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    if (_shuttingDown) return;
    _shuttingDown = true;

    var close = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close the programm?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    if (close == MessageBoxResult.No) 
    {
        _shuttingDown = false;
        return;
    }

    Application.Current.Shutdown();     
}
```

Comment: Awesome! glad I could help.